# xsl translate or lower-case shows up js error, how to compare without casesensitivity in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am getting this error

```
Unknown method.-->translate(STATUS<--,'abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')='ERROR']
```

When I am using following line

```
<td width="7"  height="17"><xsl:if test="translate(STATUS,'abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')='ERROR'"><img src="../../../Images/Error.png" alt="" /></xsl:if></td>
```

In the below following block

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">
  <xsl:template>
      <table id='tblEntries' index='0' class="GridText" style="table-layout:fixed;width=100%">
        <xsl:for-each select="SERVICES-OBJECT/ITEM" >
          <tr id='trEntries' onmouseover="this.style.cursor='default'">

          <td width="7"  height="17"><xsl:if test="translate(STATUS,'abcdefghijlkmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')='ERROR'"><img src="../../../Images/Error.png" alt="" /></xsl:if></td>

          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>
```

I tried `XSLT` try editor with a similar sample, it works without errors on the same browser. Should some `XSL` namespaces be included for the first to make it work?

But this line works well

```
 <td width="7"  height="17"><xsl:if test="ACTIONSTATUS[.='ERROR']">
  <img src="../../../Common/Graphics/ar_urgent.png" alt="" /></xsl:if>
 </td>
```

but I want to compare ignoring case sensitiviness

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">
```

to

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
```

as that is the correct namespace for the W3C XSLT standard while the one you used is related to a very old (before 1999) working draft that only very old versions of MSXML support.

Comment: Thank Honnen for the suggestion,  I had tried that before and the browser shows me the following error
Required attribute 'version' is missing.

Comment: Yes, right, I only corrected the namespace, but for the W3C standard you also need a version attribute e.g. `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">` if you run your XSLT in the browser with the XSLT 1.0 processors available there or `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">` if you can use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XML Prime or AltovaXML or perhaps Saxon CE.